# Creating class instance in same method for multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a question. I have a method `Processrequest()` which supports multithreading, can each thread create one class instance of `Requestclass` and work on its own.

Eg.,

```
public class Requestclass : producerclass 
{
    public override string Generaterequest();
}


public class producerclass
{
    public virtual string Generaterequest();

    Public void Processrequest(){
        string request = Generaterequest();
        //HttpWebRequest here
        // process the request here
    }

}
```

For one instance of Requestclass, it works fine. But I would like to know how to proceed in this scenario

1. I have multiple request class
2. These request class name will be dynamic.
3. Since it supports multithreading i.e., each thread should process one request class concurrently.

(Edit: If I have multiple Requestclass, how to create instance in Processrequest() method. Whether the instance created in each thread will be maintained?)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to achieve your goal

Comment: how can Requestclass `override` anything?

Comment: @MrWombat I have updated my question. Generaterequest() in Requestclass overrides virtual Generaterequest()  in producerclass.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the goal is, but if you're looking to have a variable that keeps an instance per thread, you might want to look at the ThreadStaticAttribute ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx )

Comment: To answer your edit: It does not matter you create your instances of the `Requestclass`(es) and when `Processrequest` is called, they will start a new Task that is only assigned to that instance. Thats inheritance

Comment: "I have multiple request class" - does this mean you have multiple _instances_ of that one class named `Requestclass`? Or are you saying you have more than one class like the class named `Requestclass`? What does "These request class name will be dynamic" mean? The code example you've provided is insufficient to know a) what you are trying to do and b) whether the code is thread-safe. If each instance of a type is used only in one thread, that's usually enough, but the class also needs to not access static members or ensure static members are thread-safe. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the scenario correct, you want to create multiple RequestClasses each generating another request that runs concurrently?
Start a new Task with the TPL for each request like:

```
public void Processrequest(){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        string request = Generaterequest();
        //access and process request here
    });
}
```

You can also add a continuation task to process the result of each started `Task`.